# How to skew a svg such that it remains in the viewport using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have appended a rectangle as svg and applied skew transformation on it. The problem is that when I drag to skew the rectangle, it is moving outside the viewport. How can I apply the skew transformation such that the rectangle remains inside the viewport or how can I skew the rectangle in its place so that it remains within the viewport? Here is what I have uptil now:

```
var width = 550, height = 400;

            var sketchSVG = d3.select("#sketch4").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged))
                .append("g");

            var rectangle = sketchSVG.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 200)
                            .attr("height", 150)
                            .attr("fill", "green");

            function dragged() {
                sketchSVG.attr("transform","skewX("+d3.event.x+")" );
                metricSVG.attr("transform","skewX("+d3.event.x+")" );
            };
```